# Is it possible to copy a CCLayer instance in cocos2x?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I created a `CCLayer` instance, and then I want to create the same layer.

Is it possible to copy a `CCLayer` instance in cocos2-x?

Comment: I don't think cocos2d-x support deep copy at the moment. the easiest way is to copy and past your code.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no such possibility in cocos2dx now. So just place creation of your layer to the method that will return result layer and call this method twice.

Answer (score 0):

Copying/deep-copying objects in cocos2d-x is not an option.

The best way is to create a custom class for your layer, and then call the `::create()` method twice to have two instances of the same layer, sharing all the initial configuration.

In `MyLayer.h`:

```
USING_NS_CC;

class MyLayer : public CCLayer {
public:
  CREATE_FUNC(MyLayer);

  virtual bool init();
};
```

In `MyLayer.cpp`:

```
bool MyLayer::init() {
  if (!CCLayer::init())
    return false;

  // Insert here all custom initialization logic

  return true;
}
```

Then you can easily do:

```
MyLayer *layer1 = MyLayer::create();
MyLayer *layer2 = MyLayer::create();
```

and both layers will share the same initial aspect/configuration/whatelse.